# How to parent a *bone* to *vertices*?

Tags: rigging, parent, vertex-groups

Nope, not vertices to a bone, a bone to vertices. I have an armature already rigged to a mesh, but I want its IK controls to move with specific vertices of another mesh. Is there a way to parent the IK bones to the vertices directly or do I need to use empties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Combine desired vertices into **Vertex Group**
- Add a **Child Of** constraint to the *bone*
- Set this **Vertex Group** as a *target* in constraint settings

[image]